# Import data from URL

Tags: orange

I put a dropbox link to the URL box in the File widget and the data got imported perfectly. I saved the workflow that I would like to share with my team. But when I reopen the workflow, the URL link is gone. Every time you save and close the workflow, the URL link get erased.

Is there a way that I can save the URL link info in the .ows file?